# Sending custom cell through segue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview

I currently have two UITableViewControllers, one with the prototype of the custom cell, and the other one not. Since both of them are connected through a push segue from the first to the second. I pass the selected custom cell to the second tableView.

Everything works fine, except that when I come back to the first view, the selected (and passed) cell is hidden, but when I scroll it enough to hide the blank space and scrolling back it shows.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I found a way to fix this, which is calling [tableView reloadData], in the viewDidAppear method. But there should be a better way to fix this without reloading the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_nd_edition_) says basically to stay away from Storyboard for just this kind of reason. 
Amongst other things about Storyboards, it says:

> "Overall storyboards make easy code easier and difficult code more difficult".

Not sure you should be passing a cell through the push segue.
When not using storyboard, you would typically create a new file of type UITableViewCell called e..g MyCustomerTableviewCell. 
Then in your UITableView viewDidLoad method, create a new Nib and add it to the tableView,

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
// register this nib that contains the cell
[[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomTableViewTableViewCell"];
```

Then create a new empty XIB file (file->new->User Interface->empty) and call it MyCustomTableViewCell.xib.
Drop a UITableViewCell into the interface builder space, change it from UITableViewCell type to MyCustomTableViewCell, make sure it's File's Owner is MyCustomTableViewCell.

Then in your UITableView file, do this...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCustomTableViewTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomTableViewCell"];
...
return cell;
}
```

You can probably do this as part of a storyboard project anyway (though I haven't tried missing XIB and Storyboard in one project).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are doing, you are passing a reference of the tapped cell to the second view controller, and then you are showing it inside the table view of the second controller passing the same reference in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.
It doesn't seems a good choice :-) 
First: because that cell was allocated and queued for use in the first view controller. At any time, the cell could receive a prepareForReuse message by the first view controller.
Second: when you show the cell in the second table view, the cell is removed from the first table view.

If you don't want to create another prototype cell in the second view controller, you can, for example, allocate a *new* cell in the first one, copy all properties from the tapped one to the new, and then pass the new to the second viewcontroller.
This is the first solution I've thought about, but sure there are other better solutions :-)

Comment: Thanks! I will copy the cell to the other tableView then. This answer is accepted too, but since Nick's answer is more detailed I'm marking his as correct.